# Conditional variable setting

Tags: scala, conditional-statements, immutability

I need to set a variable depending on a condition. But since variables are immutable, I find myself in a sticky situation having to repeat code. What I'd like to do is:

```
def doSomething(x:Int):Int = {
  if(x==1){
    val player="Andy"
  } else {
    val player="Rob"
  }
  getSomeValue(player) // Another function
}
```

But the variable "player" is no longer in scope. Only way I see is to call the function "getSomeValue" in both the condition blocks, but that's not something I'd like to do. How do I get around this using immutable variables?

Comment: Just a minor remark: *variables* (`var`) are not immutable in Scala, but *values* (`val`) are. But `val` is the idiomatic default and you should prefer it over `var`. Acutally the same is true for Java, but it's really awkward having to write `final int x` all the time.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of var and mutable variables. I was under the impression that immutable variables is one of the strengths (?) of Functional Programming.

Comment: Well, you can declare variables `final` in Java, too. And it's good style to do so whenever it's possible. C++ also has a very nice way of declaring things `const` (more powerful than Java's `final`). The strength of Scala, in this regard, is making *immutable by default* an easy to achieve thing, and not a verbose mess as it is in Java.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
def doSomething(x:Int):Int = {
  val player = if(x==1){
    "Andy"
  } else {
    "Rob"
  }
  getSomeValue(player)
}
```

Comment: or in short: `def doSomething(x: Int) = getSomeValue(if (x == 1) "Andy" else "Rob")`

Comment: Thanks so much for that! My Java Oriented brain still needs some functional third degree to get used to this.